# [SOLVED] How can i install robot_localization?

Tags: navigation, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I tried:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-robot_localization
```

it installed the package but then when i enter:

```
roslaunch robot_localization ekf_template.launch
```

I get this:

> ```
> error loading <rosparam> tag: 
>   file does not exist [/opt/ros/kinetic/share/robot_localization/params/ekf_template.yaml]
> ```

so i went to /opt/ros/kinetic/share/robot_localization/  and saw that indeed a bunch of files and folders were missing (im comparing to the git repository -> https://github.com/cra-ros-pkg/robot_localization)

i cant download the repository directly into that directory. and theres no build guide for this package.
maybe someone here knows what to do?
thank you

**EDIT:**

Ok so i found a workaround. instead of using  $ sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-robot_localization
I went into my catkin_ws src folder and opened a terminal. then i entered:

```
git clone -b kinetic-devel https://github.com/cra-ros-pkg/robot_localization.git
```

then

```
cd ~/catkin_ws 
catkin_make
```

now its installed correctlly with all the files and folders :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/271213/%5Bsolved%5D-how-can-i-install-robot_localization?/) by [Jair](https://answers.ros.org/users/31754/jair/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-09-20

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-09-21**:
You should write up your solution as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This looks like an oversight in the upstream package. I've filed the following PR:

https://github.com/cra-ros-pkg/robot_localization/pull/376

---

Originally posted by [mikepurvis](https://answers.ros.org/users/270/mikepurvis/) with karma: 1153 on 2017-09-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jair](https://answers.ros.org/users/31754/jair/) on 2017-09-21**:
Hi i'm new to ROS (and Linux also). may i ask, so what happened here? it wasnt wrong to use "sudo apt-get install" ? using that command should have worked right off the bat?

**Comment by [mikepurvis](https://answers.ros.org/users/270/mikepurvis/) on 2017-09-21**:
You did everything right. It's just the particular parameter file that that launch file depended on wasn't being installed by the binary version of the package. This is a bug for the package maintainer to fix, but you successfully worked around it by building from source and using the devel space.

**Comment by [Jair](https://answers.ros.org/users/31754/jair/) on 2017-09-21**:
Thank you very much mikepurvis.
I think i'm finally starting to get how ROS works.
man the beginning is kinda tough, especially if youre also totally new to linux

very nice community here thanks for the awesome explanation :)